# Application crashing with segue identifier in UITableViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, storyboard, segue

I am trying make a segue call in a tableview , but the application crashes when I click on the cell ...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       switch (indexPath.row){
        case 0:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segue1" sender: self];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segue2" sender: self];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self button1];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self button2];
            break;  
}
```

case 2 and 3 work perfectly fine , but case 0 and 1 crash with the following green error :

```
thread 1:Program received signal "SIGBART".
```

thanks

Comment: Check your segues are named the same as in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the table/cell you are clicking on is associated with a view controller that has a storyboard.

The storyboard initiates the segue so when you say

```
[self ...]
```

It's saying tell MY storyboard to initiate the segue.

see [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier%3asender%3a)

> Initiates the segue with the specified identifier from ***the view controller’s storyboard*** file.